# Get List Names of all Lists using particular site columns

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I need to get the names of all the lists using specific site columns. I've got the following code

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://nameofsite/sites/subsite"
$filePath = "E:\lists.txt"
$array = "array of site column names"

foreach ($element in $array)
{
  $column = $web.Fields[$element]
  $column.ListsFieldUsedIn() | Out- File -FilePath $filePath -Append

}
```

But what it's doing is sending the web id and the list id to the file. Is there any way to get the id returned from $column.ListsFieldUsedIn() to return the name of the list?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access **Fields** property from **Web** instance.

Warning! Not Tested Code...

```
        $site = Get-SPSite "http://nameofsite/sites/subsite"
        $array = "array of site column names"

        foreach($element in $array) 
        {
            $field = $site.RootWeb.AvailableFields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Attachments];
            Write-Host "The $($field.Title) Field is used in: "
            Write-Host "-->"

            $collection = $field.ListsFieldUsedIn()
            foreach($usage in $collection)
            {
                $web = $site.AllWebs[$usage.WebID]
                $list = $web.Lists[$usage.ListID]

                Write-Host "$($list.Title) list in $($web.Title)"
                $web.Dispose()
            }
        }

        $site.Dispose()
```

See the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.listsfieldusedin.aspx) for more info

Comment: Thanks for the information! I tried your suggestion above and I get the same results as I did in my code. I get a list of WWeb ids and a list of list ids. The ids are the same between the two code versions. What I'm wondering is how I can then get the **list names** associated with those list ids.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://nameofsite/sites/subsite"
$filePath = "E:\lists.txt"
$array = "array of site column names"    
$column = $site.RootWeb.AvailableFields[$element]
$lists = $column.ListsFieldUsedIn()
$column.ListsFieldUsedIn() | ForEach-Object {
    $w = $site.AllWebs[$_.WebID]
    $l = $w.Lists[$_.ListID]
     "Web:" +$w.Title+ "  List: " + $l.Title+ " ListUrl: " +$l.RootFolder.Url | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Append 

    }
```

Based on code I found here [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/is-it-possible-to-iterate-all-lists-in-sharepoint-in-search-for-a-given-field)